# How can I repair these cracks in my balcony wall?

Tags: walls, crack

I have recently purchased a flat which around three years old. The house is on 11th floor and has vertical cracks on balcony walls. Some of them are across the wall. Here are some pictures

[Wall crack pictures](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4pNmoIAuAckRkx0eHN6REV5TlE&usp=sharing)

I am more worried about the one in the picture below. This appears to be across the wall.

[image]

Question is is it a safety issue? And what is the best way to repair this.

Comment: Is the building assembled from pre-fabricated enforced concrete parts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to know if these cracks are structural or cosmetic, without knowing many construction and assembly details (such as the use of pre-stressed, reinforced panels).

This is would be in the domain of a structural engineer.

If cosmetic, an elastomeric, exterior grade concrete crack filler would be advisable. [Sika products](http://usa.sika.com/en/solutions_products/02/02a007.html) come to mind